# `stringr::str_glue`: how to escape backslash (\)?

Tags: r, stringr, r-glue

I'd like `str_glue` to keep `\` when I glue, but I don't understand how to escape it.

I have this `reprex` with the logical attempts I've made: (escaping the escape, etc)

```r
library(stringr)
var <- "darkness"

str_glue("Hello {var} my old friend \
I've come to talk with you again")
#> Hello darkness my old friend 
#> I've come to talk with you again

str_glue("Hello {var} my old friend \\
I've come to talk with you again")
#> Hello darkness my old friend I've come to talk with you again

str_glue("Hello {var} my old friend \\\
I've come to talk with you again")
#> Hello darkness my old friend I've come to talk with you again
```

Created on 2021-04-28 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)

**My desired output:**

```
"Hello darkness my old friend \
I've come to talk with you again"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
var <- "darkness"
stringr::str_glue("Hello {var} my old friend \\\ \n I've come to talk with you again")
#> Hello darkness my old friend \ 
#> I've come to talk with you again
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>